# Can I use a distinct Protocol Buffer version for Pig jobs than the underlying hadoop infrastructure uses?

Tags: apache-pig, protocol-buffers, thrift

A hadoop cluster I work on appears to deploy with a protocol buffer jar for its own use.  I would like to write Pig scripts that store using its own version of protocol buffers by means of a UDF.  Is it possible for my UDFs to use a different version of protocol buffers than the underlying hadoop system?

For context, compiled protocol buffer code should not be interchanged among versions even though the wire format can be.  So I would need assurances that if I am supplying my jar I am not replacing the standard variant for Hadoop internal work.  Also, I find the supplied standard version of protocol buffers on my cluster incompatible with the compiled message I supplied (confirmed).

At issue here is whether I need to have versions of the protocol buffer library 100% in sync at all times between the cluster and my library code.  This would introduce tight coupling and future maintenance headaches.  I am likely to switch over to Thrift which apparently has no pre-existing dependencies on the cluster.

Comment: This is an odd question. Technically, as long as your code is compiled with your version of the compiled Java *.proto file, YES?! When you say "with a protocol buffer jar", is this the reading jar, and can you tell me what version that it is? Will need to do more research, but I think the answer is yes because twitter did something like this... Also, in the OSS world Avro is more common to see in Hadoop than Protobuf, do you know what else on the cluster(if not, or you no want to share thats ok) could possibly be using it?

Comment: My Pig UDF is compiled against protocol buffer version 3.3.0, and this same version of protoc is used to generate the .java files from the .proto file.  However, on the cluster there are jar files associated with protocol buffer 2.4 which I assume are used by Hadoop internals.  I would rather use the later version for my UDF to move things forward.  However, I don't want my protocol version to be picked up by the Hadoop internals nor get ignored at runtime since the earlier version is there and presumably on some CLASSPATH.